# Android Dagger2 Dependency Injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm new to Dagger2 and I'm trying to use dependency injection in my application.
I'm using shared preferences and thought it will be more helpful to use dependency injection instead of getting an instance of shared prefrences each time I need to use it.
It works fine when I'm using it on activities and fragments but when I'm trying to use it on service or intentservice it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

**AppModule:**

```
@Module
public class AppModule
{
    public final ApplicationClass application;

    public AppModule(ApplicationClass application)
    {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext()
    {
        return this.application;
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences()
    {
        return application.getSharedPreferences(Constants.FILE_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{
    void inject (ApplicationClass applicationClass);
    void inject (IntentService intentService);
    void inject (Service service);
}
```

**ApplicationClass**

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application
{
    AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new 
        Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                onUncaughtException(t, e);
            }
        });

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                       .builder()
                       .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                       .build();

        appComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public AppComponent getAppComponent()
    {
        return this.appComponent;
    }

    private void onUncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Intent crash= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Crash.class);
        about.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(crash);      
    }
}
```

So I tried to inject the shared preferences in IntentService and I used these lines of code 
inside the onCreate method of the my service (intentservice)

```
@Inject
SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    ((ApplicationClass)getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
}
```

But the problem is when I use this preferences variable in the `onHandleIntent` method, the application is crashing because the preferences is null..
So why it doesn't inject?

Comment: You don't have to inject context and shared preferences to IntentService, IntentService has already inherited from Context. Your problem is that you should use name on target class (in inject method) in AppComponent for examle:     `void inject (ApplicationClass applicationClass);
    void inject (CustomIntentService intentService);
    void inject (SimpleIntentService service);`

Comment: You need to specify a **specific concrete class** and not its parent class to inject in it. So you can't just say `IntentService` and inject into any intent service, it will be null because your class is not `IntentService`, it is `WhateverService`.

Comment: @VadimKorzun thanks as you can see I meant shared preferences and edited my question. 
Thanks for your clarify about my problem

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thank you also ! 
I thought that if I passing to the inject method the IntentService as parameter I could use this function for all the classes in my app that are inherit from IntentService. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who encountered this problem. 
As Vadim Korzun and EpicPandaForce mentioned in their comments above,
I should specify the specific class in the inject method.

So in my case my IntentService class was named `GeofenceService`

and inside the AppComponent interface I should write

```
void inject (GeofenceService service);
```

Same thing for `Service`

**UPDATE:**

So for all the people who have multiple Services that inherit from IntentService and want to save themselves from writing inject method for each Specific service.
I would suggest to do the steps below:

1. Create `BasicIntentService` that **extends** `IntentService`
2. In your `AppComponent` interface add the inject method which take as parameter you `BasicIntentService`.
3. In your `BasicIntentSerive`, you will have a `protected SharedPrefrences` variable annotated with the `Inject` annotation.
4. Still, in your `BasicIntentService`, inside the `onCreate` method you will call this line of code

   ((ApplicationClass)getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
5. Now each `IntentService` that you will create will **extends** the `BasicIntentService` and you will be able to use the `SharedPreferences` variable.

---

**AppComponent:**

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent
{
    void inject (YourApplicationClass applicationClass);
    void inject (BasicIntentService intentService);
}
```

**BasicIntentService**

```
public class BasicIntentService extends IntentService
{
   @Inject
   protected SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

   @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
       super.onCreate()
       ((YourApplicationClass)getApplication()).getAppComponenet().inject(this);
   } 
}
```

**SomeIntentService**

```
public class SomeIntentService extends BasicIntentService 
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate()
   {
      super.onCreate();
   }
   -----------
   @Override
   protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent)
   {
     // some code
     if (sharedPreferences.contains(someKey))
     {
         // some code
     }
     else
     {
        // some code
     }
   }

}
```